# Why is this string operator not registering valid match with fetch_assoc()?

Tags: php, string, mysqli, operators

As the code is, I think the associative value of 'aurapass' is picking up as a string rather than the corresponding fetch value. Everything is returning positive. How do I select the fetch_assoc() value?

```
        $recruiter=$_POST["recruiter"];
        $aurapass=$_POST["aurapass"];
        $recruitfetch=mysqli_query($maindb, "SELECT * FROM auras WHERE auraname = $recruiter");
        $recruitcheck=mysqli_fetch_assoc($recruitfetch);
        if($recruitcheck['aurapass']==$aurapass){
              if($recruitcheck['recruitbadge']=="valid"){
              echo "<script>alert('Recruiter badge verified.')</script>";
              }
        }
```

I have since changed the variables to be different words, so I can test the true value of the variables, and the column names, and string value of "valid" matches the table database values, so what I the problem, here?

With changes, the current code reads:

```
      $recruiter=$_POST["recruiter"];
      $recruitpass=$_POST["recruitpass"];
      $recruitfetch=mysqli_query($maindb, "SELECT * FROM auras WHERE auraname = '$recruiter'");
      $recruitcheck=mysqli_fetch_assoc($recruitfetch);
      if($recruitcheck['aurapass']==$recruitpass){
             if($recruitcheck['recruitbadge']=="valid"){
             echo "<script>alert('Recruiter badge verified.')</script>";
             }
      }
```

I am struggling to receive any sort of printout, or echo, to show the values of anything. I am extremely new to this, and struggling. Unfortunately, I have not found sites that talk about exact syntax, especially with PHP7.0. Any advice on troubleshooting this would be fantastic!

Comment: Replace `==` to `===` ?

Comment: Where is `$aurapass` being defined?

Comment: `$recruiter` is a string?

Comment: Is `@POST['aurapass']` a typo or did you use `$POST['aurapass']` instead of `$_POST['aurapass']`

Comment: You need quotes around `$recruiter` in the SQL. But it would better if you used a prepared query.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the quotes to recruiter did change the results, so apparently the code is correct in the second version, but I think I had some sort of character errors because I had to retype it to get it to work, but it is still the same exact text?

This is what I ended with:

```
$recruiter=$_POST["recruiter"];
$recruitpass=$_POST["recruitpass"];
$recruitfetch=mysqli_query($maindb, "SELECT * FROM auras WHERE auraname = '$recruiter'");
$recruitcheck=mysqli_fetch_assoc($recruitfetch);
if($recruitcheck["aurapass"]==$recruitpass){
      if($recruitcheck["recruitbadge"]=="valid"){
```

I also figured out how to print a var_dump, and I understand its use. Thank you, all!